# Convert image/object to lines

Tags: vector

I am creating an algorithm and I need your help. I have this vector file (SVG) and I would like to know if is there a way I can export/convert this image to lines only?

Something like this: [image]

Think about a circle with radius N. I would like Corel or Photoshop or any tool to convert this circle with radius N to multiple lines (which I could define as many as I want) in such a way that those lines represent the outline of the circle. I just would like to know the start X,Y  and end X,Y coordinates of every line so I could export it to a txt file like this:

0,0 100,100 (which means draw a line from 0,0 to 100,100)
100,100 200,200 (which means draw a line from 100,00 to 200,00)
...
..
-100,100 0,0 (finishes the circle by drawing the last line from -100,100 to 0,0).

How could I do that?

Answer (score -1):

Converting image (bitmap) to lines (vectors) called "tracing". You can trace bitmaps to .svg files in open source vector editor "Inkscape" - available for free for Linux, Windows and Mac.